# Error 500 when a try access to Backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I come here with a problem that I can not solve.

I have a prestashop in version 1.7 that I have moved to another server, it is worth mentioning that in the old server the prestashop is working well.

When I have migrated the prestashop to the new server, everything works well except when I want to enter the Backoffice, when I want to enter the Backoffice, simply leaves the page blank.

I have activated the debug mode, but it doesn't give me any error related to Backoffice, the interesting thing is that when the debug mode is activated, I can enter the Backoffice without problem.

The only thing I can see is that it gives me an error 500 but it doesn't tell me anything else.

I don't know if anyone can give me any idea of what might be happening in this case, thank you.

Comment: Did you check your (new server) error logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have this kind of problem, the best solution is to remove the cache:

**On Prestashop 1.6**: delete the contents of the cache / smarty / cache and cache / smarty / compile folders

**On Prestashop 1.7**: delete the var / cache folder

Regards,

Comment: Thank u this was the problema

Comment: Ok please, Can you validate the answer so that other people who would have this problem can have the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all cache. Delete files in /app/cache

Answer (score 1):

I think can not be solved by deleting cache you should debug it further.
Most probably the error could be due to php version change.

follow this steps:

1. Check php version of old hosting
2. apply php version of old hosting to new one